# How to turn off autocorrect when using on mobile

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

I have issue when using react-bootstrap-typeahead on mobile. I want to turn off autocorrect of input but i don't know how to do it.

please help me.
thank all so much.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use the [`spellcheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-spellcheck) attribute (as well as [`autocorrect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocorrect) in Safari) on inputs to disable these features. In react-bootstrap-typeahead, you can set these values using the `inputProps` prop:

```
<Typeahead
  inputProps={{
    autoCorrect: 'off', // Safari-only
    spellCheck: false,
  }}
/>
```

However, note that [according to caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=spellcheck):

> The partial support in mobile browsers results from their OS generally having built-in spell checking instead of using the wavy underline to indicate misspelled words. spellcheck="false" does not seem to have any effect in these browsers.

So, it may not be possible to fully disable autocorrect in mobile browsers since that can be up to the individual's OS-level settings.

Comment: thank you so much, but if i use `AsyncTypeahead`  is it work. i view html it has not atttribute autocorrect. I will browser chrome

Comment: I made a mistake in my original answer. The attributes need to be camelCased (ie: `autoCorrect` & `spellCheck`). Answer updated.